# JDBC exception at getting decimal out parameter of stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, out-parameters

I'm trying to get parameter from MYSQL procedure.
My proc:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE proc(someIn INT UNSIGNED, 
                      anotherIn INT UNSIGNED, 
                      OUT x DECIMAL(10,7),
                      OUT y DECIMAL(10,7))
```

My java code:

```java
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call proc(?, ?,?,?)}");
cs.setLong(1, someLong);
cs.setLong(2, anotherLong);
cs.registerOutParameter(3,Types.DECIMAL,7);
cs.registerOutParameter(4,Types.DECIMAL,7);
rs = cs.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    double x = rs.getBigDecimal(3).doubleValue(); 
    double y = rs.getBigDecimal(4).doubleValue();
}
```

And I encountered on error at calling rs.next():

> java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.

If I call the procedure with the same parameters manually, I get the result data.
I tried to change decimal to double, but this has no effect.

Comment: Lukas was right. Thank you, Lukas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to call the procedure is this:

```
cs.execute();
double x = cs.getBigDecimal(3).doubleValue(); 
double y = cs.getBigDecimal(4).doubleValue();
```